# How can I make a single Button play music, pause music and unpause music in Python using tkinter and pygame?

Tags: python, tkinter, audio, pygame

I've only been able to get the program to play music when the button is pushed. Everything I've tried to pause or stop the music has ended in failure. I feel like I should be using an if statement to pause the music if it's currently playing or to unpause it if it's not but I need to understand the proper way to write that. Would this be the correct approach?  I really want to be able to start, pause and unpause the music from a single button but I'm struggling to figure out how to go about coding that. Here is my code to play the music.

```
 def Play_music():
     pygame.mixer.music.load('tavernsound.mp3')
     pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

and here is the code for the button:

```
btn11=Button(labelframe, text='Ambiance', width=14, bg='red', fg='black', command=Play_music)
btn11.pack(side=LEFT)
```

Comment: Maybe you can toggle the state? Like if playing is a boolean, `playing = not playing`

Answer (score 1):

Use Check Button Text with an if condition
Example :

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button
from pygame import mixer

root = Tk()
root.title("Play Music")
root.geometry('350x200')

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load("sound.mp3")

def play_music():
    if button["text"] == "Play":
        button["text"] = "Pause"
        button["bg"] = "red"
        mixer.music.play()
    else:
        button["text"] = "Play"
        button["bg"] = "green"
        mixer.music.pause()

button = Button(root, text='Play', width=14, bg='green', fg='black', command=play_music)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def doSomething(task):
    global var, button
    if task == 0:
        var.set("Started Playing")
        button.configure(text = "Pause")
        button.configure(command = lambda task = 1: doSomething(task))
        #play
    elif task == 1:
        var.set("Paused")
        button.configure(text = "Resume")
        button.configure(command = lambda task = 0: doSomething(task))
        #pause

button = Button(root, text = "Play", command = lambda task = 0: doSomething(task))
button.pack()
var = StringVar()
label = Label(root, textvariable = var)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Here the same button is used to play, pause and resume. I have used the `lambda` function which has the syntax `lambda arguments: expression`. The `task` value changes every time the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I used your code to create this example. It changes the button text based on the @AST answer:

```
from tkinter import *
import pygame

root = Tk()
root.title("MSC")

pygame.init()

mxstate = 0 # music play state

pygame.mixer.music.load('tavernsound.mp3')

def Play_music():
     global mxstate
     if mxstate == 0:  # music not started
         pygame.mixer.music.play()
         btn11.configure(text = "Pause")
         mxstate =  1
         return
        
     if mxstate == 1:  # music playing
         pygame.mixer.music.pause()
         btn11.configure(text = "Resume")
     else:  # music paused
         pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
         btn11.configure(text = "Pause")
     mxstate = 3-mxstate  # swap pause state
     
btn11=Button(root, text='Ambiance', width=14, bg='red', fg='black', command=Play_music)
btn11.pack(side=LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That works flawlessly and is exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks for teaching me something new. The if statements I tried weren't working because I didn't create a variable for the music play state. Why do I need this line:  mxstate =  3-mxstate ? I get what it's doing but I don't really understand how it's working.

Comment: @Slacker the `mxstate = 3-mxstate  # swap pause state` is not the clearest way to handle that. Instead remove that line and at the end of the `if mxstate == 1:  # music playing` block add `mxstate = 2  # set to paused state` and also at the end of the `else:  # music paused` block add `mxstate = 1  # set to playing state`. That is what the `mxstate = 3-mxstate` is doing, swapping back and forth between mxstate of 1 and 2 by subtracting mxstate (1 or 2) from 3. 
Mike67 might want to clarify that part of the answer.